# Where is the best place to store/retrieve networking/url config stuff access from within Android Library

Tags: android

I have a library project in Android which encapsulates network access.  So if user needs to do a search for example they call DataAccessLibrary.find(searchTerm).

They do not need to call DataAccessLibrary.find(searchServerURL, searchTerm).

My question is where should I store on the client these URL's.  The library does not have its own context so where should it obtain server names, ports etc.

I don't really want the Activities to pass this information to the library.  I want the library alone to know where to get this stuff, and retrieve it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the URL as a String resource.

```
<string name="lirbrary.url">http://www.example.com</string>
```

Your library can use this URL however it likes by loading it from the resources.

```
context.getResources().getString(R.string.library_url);
```

And a user can override it by supplying a String resource with the same name.

Comment: this might be right.  If others agree with this answer please click the up arrow. What about shared preferences?